# Devise gem error while deploying with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, devise, capistrano

I'm trying to make a deployment of my Ruby on Rails application using capistrano but after running:

```
cap production deploy:initial
```

Deploy fails and display the next error:

```
rake aborted!
      01 NoMethodError: undefined method `devise' for Client (call 'Client.connection' to establish a connection):Class
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/releases/20190611034848/app/models/client.rb:2:in `<class:Client>'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/releases/20190611034848/app/models/client.rb:1:in `<main>'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:378:in `block in require_or_load'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `block in load_interlock'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:14:in `block in loading'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:151:in `exclusive'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5
      01 .0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:13:in `loading'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:37:in `load_interlock'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:356:in `require_or_load'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:48:in `block in require_or_load'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:47:in `require_or_load'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:510:in `load_missing_constant'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:60:in `block in load_missing_constant'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:16:in `allow_bootsnap_retry'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:59:in `load_missing_constant'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:195:in `const_missing'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `const_get'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:283:in `block in constantize'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `each'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `inject'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:281:in `constantize'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:582:in `get'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:613:in `constantize'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise.rb:320:in `get'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:83:in `to'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:78:in `modules'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:95:in `routes'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:162:in `default_used_route'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `initialize'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise.rb:350:in `new'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise.rb:350:in `add_mapping'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:243:in `block in devise_for'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `each'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/devise-4.6.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `devise_for'
      01
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/releases/20190611034848/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <main>'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:414:in `draw'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/releases/20190611034848/config/routes.rb:1:in `<main>'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `load'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `block in load'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `load'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in load_paths'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `each'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `load_paths'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:20:in `reload!'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:30:in `block in updater'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:83:in `execute'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `execute'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:130:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
      01
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/releases/20190611034848/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
      01
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
      01
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
      01 /home/deploy/apps/tuti/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
      01
      01 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
      01 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
      01 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
      01 Tasks: TOP => environment
      01 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
#<Thread:0x00007ff438868790@/Users/danielavila/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from /Users/danielavila/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/danielavila/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing on host XXX.XX.XX.XXX: rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
```

It seems to be an error with the `Devise` gem but I have being trying to fix it for a couple hours and I'm running out of ideas.

The rails app runs locally with no problems.

This is my `Capfile`

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/puma'

install_plugin Capistrano::Puma

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

And this is my `deploy.rb`:

```
# Change these
server 'XXX.XX.XX.XXX', port: 22, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        'git@gitlab.com:warelan/e-commerce/tuti.git'
set :application,     'tuti'
set :user,            'deploy'
set :use_sudo,        true
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

Comment: Are you sure you did the next command and commit all files `bundle exec rails generate devise:install` ?

Comment: Yes since locally it runs without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my on question hopefully it can be useful for someone in the future. The problem was that apparently the model needed to extend from `Device::Models`, I did not find anything in the Devise documentation but after adding `extend Devise::Models` to my `Client` model the error did not show anymore.

```rb
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Devise::Models

  # All my methods here

end
```

If someone knows why this happened it would be great if you could comment why.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you run your rails app locally with Production / Stage Environment.

`rails s RAILS_ENV=production`
`rails server -e production`

Check all are working fine